# Delphi XE3: Chr Ansi Version?

Tags: delphi, unicode, ansi, delphi-xe3, chr

I have my own D6 pas library with crypto functions.
Today I tried to use it under XE3, and I found many bugs in it because of unicode.
I tried to port to AnsiString, but I failed on chr(nnn) which was 8 bit limited under Delphi6.

I'm trying to explain the problem:

```
    Str := chr(hchar);
    AStr := Str;
```

Str - string; AStr - ansistring.

When the hchar was 216 (diamater), then AStr changed to "O", what is Ascii 79...
And I lost the original value at this moment.

Is there any function for Ansi Chr? For example: "AChr(xxxx)"

Or I need to change my code to not use Strings in the inner section, only bytes and later convert these bytes to AnsiString?

Thanks for any suggestion, help, info!

dd

Comment: Encrypting is about bytes, not about characters. Make sure your code works with byte structures (arrays of bytes) in Delphi 6 first (use a testing framework like DUnit to verify correctness). Then port your code to newer Delphi versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `AnsiChar(SomeOrdinalValue)` to make an `AnsiChar` with a specific ordinal. So your code should be:

```
AStr := AnsiChar(hchar);
```

The problem with the code in the question is that you converted to UTF-16 and back.

It would seem to me that strings are the wrong type for your crypto code. Use a byte array, `TBytes`.